# Sum up all values from a MySql row and display them as a total

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to display the sum of an affiliate's total commisions. For this I have to add all of his incomes from the database. This is my code, but as a result, instead of displaying the total ammount, It displays "Array". I know it should be someething simple, but can someone give me a hand with this please?

```
    $query = 'SELECT SUM(ammount) FROM affiliate_income WHERE id_affiliate = '.$id_user;
$sum = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$total = mysql_fetch_assoc($sum);
```

Comment: `print $total['SUM(amount)'];`. The `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns an array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Krister. what should I use instead?

Comment: You could do like I did above. Something like: `$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sum); $total = $result['SUM(ammount)'];`

Answer (score 1):

Instead od `$total = mysql_fetch_assoc($num)` I would use something like this:

```
while ($total = mysql_fetch_array($sum))
{ echo $total[0]; }
```

But to feed the bandwagon, try to shift away from mysql* specific functions and use the PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
 $query = "SELECT SUM(ammount) as tot FROM affiliate_income WHERE id_affiliate = '$id_user' ";
 $sum = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
 while($total = mysql_fetch_assoc($sum))
    {
    echo $total['tot'] .'<br />';
    }
```